# Error when trying to debug Flex Application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am using Windows XP and flex builder 3. Here is the error I am receiving:

[image: Error Screenshot]

I am trying to debug a flex application by toggling a break point. When I try to  debug, I get the above error.

so far the only thing I installed is flex builder 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install in this order and you will be able to mitigate this problem. It took me a little bit of trial and error.

step 1:
http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

step 2: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/10/flashplayer_10_ax_debug.exe

Answer (score 0):

Not much you're giving us to go on - have you tried installing the [Flash 10 Debug Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)?